# Javascript. How to prevent html symbols from being replaced by &lt; &quot; and so on

Tags: javascript, ajax

My code is

```
var button = document.createElement('a');
button.innerHTML = '<div class="some_class"><div>Download</div><div class="quality">'+ element[1] +' ('+ element[2] + 'ГБ)</div></div>';
```

I load this script via ajax and I would like it to execute.
But browser loads it as:

```
button.innerHTML = '&lt;divclass=&quot;some_class&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;Download&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;quality&quot;&gt;'+ element[1] +' ('+ element[2] + 'ГБ)&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;'
```

Which causes syntax error of course.

How to fix it?

**EDIT**: if I go to the page directly http://myserver.com/script.js - it works properly. But if I use ajax for loading it like this:

```
$.ajax({url: "http://myserver.com/script.js?url=" + 
location.href, dataType: "script"});
```

It gets HTMLEncoded.

Comment: This won't solve the problem but why do you put a `div` inside `a` element? Quite unusual. And why do you call `a` element `button`. Don't you think that code should be readable and straightforward?

Comment: @Mikhail I'm not sure where your values are getting HTMLEncoded, thats really the route of the "problem" I guess. (although probably is doing it for security reasons).  But the code you posted does not show the actual problem because taken at face value it will work... http://jsfiddle.net/6kYP9/

Comment: @StephenJames I've added some explanation. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I am very grateful for the code review. But I use bootstrap for this project and yes, is usual practice to call links with button names and use 'btn' class for them. So if I call it button there are some reasons (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) for that. And if I put div elements inside - there are some reasons for that also.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out where such conversion is applied. It may be server side or your ajax library. I recommend you to look at 'network' page in browser Developer Tools. There you can see what you get from server exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var replaceStrings = {
"&": "&amp;",
"<": "&lt;",
">": "&gt;",
'"': '&quot;',
"'": '&#39;',
"/": '&#x2F;'


};

  function escapeHtmlCharacters(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (str) {
      return replaceStrings[str];
    });
```

}

Or simply

```
html.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                  .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                  .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                  .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                  .replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
```

Answer (score 0):

solved. thanks to all.

added .htmlsafe method to Rails View.